# On a circle, will a point moving in irrational steps ever land at a point it has been at previously?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory

Suppose you have a circle of radius 1 and a point on that circle. The point now moves in a clockwise direction around the circle in steps with length $\sqrt 2$.  Will that point ever land on a point it has previously been at?

I think the answer is no, but not sure how to prove it.

Actually, does the step have to be an irrational length? Would any point stepping at rational lengths ever hit a previous position?

**Edit**

The only possible case I can see where the point would hit a previous point is if it was moving in increments of $\frac{\pi}{n}$ where $n$ is some rational number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After $n$ steps the  position (=angle) relative to where your started  is  $n d  \mod 2\pi$, where $d$ is the increment length.

Therefore you return to a previously visited point if and only  for some $n$,  $n d \equiv 0 \mod 2\pi$. That is $nd = 2\pi k$ for some integer $k$. Equivalently if and only if  $d$ is a rational times $2\pi$.

Comment: And is it known that no number, rational or irrational, is a divisor of $\pi$? Other than $\pi$ I mean.

Comment: @Jens: If you take the trouble to formulate that question more precisely, you will probably find that it answers itself.

Comment: Why, $\pi\over2$ is a "divisor" of $\pi$, and a lot of other numbers too. However, they all have something in common...

Answer (score 1):

If the step distance $k$ is a rational multiple of $π$, the stepper will (eventually) reach the same points again, and in fact will do so with period  $lcm(a,b)$ for $k=a×π/b$ as a necessary outcome of the way steps are made.
Any other step distance may eventually come arbitrarily close to any previously visited point, but will never actually reach any of them.

Comment: That is my thought as well. But how can this be proved?

Comment: that is because $\pi$ is a very special kind of irrational number.

Comment: @Luis Vera - special how?

Comment: Consider how far the stepper must travel to reach the same point again. Now, what can this distance be expressed as?

Comment: @Jens a very transcendental kind...

Comment: Some rational multiple of $\pi$, right?

Comment: Then C=πx/y, so the distance is w×C=wπx/y for w,x,y integer. Then a step distance that divides this is necessary, and is of the same form. I should also note, this assumes a rational value for the radius. Things get more complicated, as Luis Vera alludes to, when it isn't rational relation.